# shorten/compress mod_rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

amongst my rules i have..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&submenu=$2&info=$3&id=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&submenu=$2&info=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&submenu=$2 [QSA,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$  index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which seems a little bulky to me and repeats a lot of stuff, any ideas on how i can shorten it?

Can i set "global" conditions?
Can i have one rule like this that captures all the ones below it (i dont care if it sends through empty varibles)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule **clever stuff here** index.php?page=$1&submenu=$2&info=$3&id=$4 [QSA,L]
```

So it would capture

domain.com/a/b/c/d
and
domain.com/a/b/c
and
domain.com/a/b
and
domain.com/a

Answers, Thoughts, Musings, and Existential Arguments all appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pretty easily remove the conditions if you check for the inverse and let it pass through the rewrite engine. Then anything *afterwards* you know isn't an existing file or directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&submenu=$2&info=$3&id=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&submenu=$2&info=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&submenu=$2 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$  index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It's not a fancy multiple-look-ahead regex that does it all in one line, but it does make it easier to read.

EDIT:

Well, like I said, you do it with multiple look-aheads, something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:([^/.]+)|)(?:/([^/.]+)|)(?:/([^/.]+)|)(?:/([^/.]+)|) index.php?page=$1&submenu=$2&info=$3&id=$4 [QSA,L]
```

But it's harder to read, and more likely to do something unexpected if you change something. Additionally, whereas having explicit 4 different mappings, you don't get blank query string params like you do with look-aheads. Whether the last `(?:/([^/.]+)|)` is there or not, you will still get an `id` param (just blank).

Comment: Brilliant, cant believe i didnt think of that! Certainly i am happy with that but i wont mark it answered until i give a little time for the regex gurus to come up with the one-liner! Thanks though.

Comment: Clearly i was in the presence of a regex guru all along.. thanks